# Cannot parse curl response as json

Tags: php, json, curl

Here is my curl php code:

```
 $ip=$cs[remoteip];
 $remoteip = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/'.$ip;
 $ch=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$remoteip);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 $output=curl_exec($ch);
 var_dump($output);die();
```

Here is the response:

```
string(250) "({"ip":"104.184.193.15","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","region_code":"FL","region_name":"Florida","city":"Boynton Beach","zip_code":"33472","time_zone":"America/New_York","latitude":26.5253,"longitude":-80.0664,"metro_code":548});"
```

Now when I do this:

```
 $output=json_decode($output);
 curl_close($ch);
 var_dump($output);die();
```

I get a `NULL` as the response.

I also tried `json_decode($output,true)` and got `NULL` as the result:

Not quite sure what to do here.

Comment: Your JSON isn't correct because of parenthesis and semicolon at the end, probably it's a jsonp format... . Get rid of them first and then parse

Comment: Json Is not valid. You can also validate your json at [jsonlint](http://http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json string has a wrong format! The first character '(' and the last two characters ');' should be removed.